# (Graded) Lie algebras with "nice" irreps

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

"(The only Lie algebras for which) all finite-dimensional representations are completely reducible (are the semisimple Lie algebras)" (Chapman, here on MO). Evidently this can't no longer hold when you consider generalizations like graded or super Lie algebras as Westbury mentions this property (call it "nice" for short - surely there already exists a proper name?) for $OSP(2,1)$ (in "R-matrices and the magic square").
In this paper I counted six nice (? - I assume it), non-semisimple, Lie algebras on the Vogel plane: $OSP(2,1),D(2,1,\alpha),A5.H20,D6.H32,C3.H14$ and the $dim=156$ thingie. I assume the list is complete (is it?) - but are there additional nice Lie algebras NOT on the Vogel plane?
(For example among the superalgebra list at Wiki, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra)
If you know an example, please also give the (defining, adjoint...) dimensions.

Comment: The link can be helpful: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdbn/Rmatrix.pdf

Comment: Ah, I see. This is a newer version of the paper with added sextonions (and a few more graded Lie algebras therein). Everything lies on the Vogel plane but THX.